# Save current storyboard watchKit

Tags: swift, xcode7, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm in trouble because I've developed a Hangman Game on the Watch but when the user win and he lock the device at the next start my storyboard info have been update but I don't want them to be updated and I don't know how to do that...
If someone can explain me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the state of the game in a local database. Then when the user restarts you Watch app, you retrieve the latest state of the game from the database and rebuild the UI in your `ExtensionDelegate` method `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

You could use Apple's [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) database, but I find the [Realm](https://realm.io/)'s mobile database much easier to use.